# Add Microsoft WSE 2.0SP3 to Microsoft .NET container

Tags: .net, docker, containers, wse

I am trying to containerize a legacy application which relies on Microsoft WSE 2.0 SP3. I wrote a nupkg for the WSE 2.0 SP3 .msi and the application, and am able to install via the nupkg to a 2012R2 server (full GUI). However, when I try to translate that method of installation to a container (microsoft/aspnet:4.7.1-windowsservercore-ltsc2016) I get msi installation failures, Error 1603. I added logging to the msi installation (/L*v C:\InstallLog.txt) however this has not given me any additional insight into the problem.

I am hoping that someone might have some more insight into the issue, know where to look for a path to resolution, or knows a better method to install WSE 2.0 SP3. Or if someone has a good example of installing WSE 2.0 SP3 on a windows container.

Answer (score 1):

Stop wasting your time on that front.

WSE is end-of-life (as Windows Server 2003 is the last environment to support it),

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/distributedservices/2012/10/25/web-service-enhancements-wse-supported-environments/

You have to upgrade to newer technologies.

Comment: Looking for a more helpful answer than that if anyone has anything.

Comment: @justlearning if you don't like 'insight' but an answer that makes you feel happy, you probably come to the wrong place. Sticking to a dead technology might be your choice, but you cannot prevent others from telling the truth.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with WSE 3.0 and would be very interested to know if you found a solution.

Comment: @DWRoelands the solution is to migrate. WSE died 19 years ago and was never supported beyond Windows Server 2003.